# datagridfield not visible in dexterity through-the-web content type editor

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've added `collective.z3cform.datagridfield` to my buildout, see it as active in my site settings; however, I cannot add a field of type `datagridfield` via the through-the-web editor for a dexterity content type.  What am I missing?

Comment: The TTW editor doesn't automatically support these additional fields. The field needs a little integration with plone.schemaeditor.

Comment: If you could point me in the right direction for integrating it with plone.schemaeditor, you might win yourself an answer.  Or if you just posted an answer instead of a comment with a bit more information as to how you learned this.  No reason for you not to earn some karma for being helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Extending vangheem's answer: You can provide support for collective.z3cform.datagridfield by providing a field factory, but it will be a hack.

Reason being is, that the `collective.z3cform.datagridfield.row.DictRow` expects a schema, defining the table rows. This becomes a subform once rendered. The schemaeditor in this instance would need to ask you depending on the field type also for the (table-) schema.

Depending on what solution you are after, you might be able to get away by implementing a field factory with a **fixed table schema** like this:

```
from five import grok
from zope import schema
import collective.z3cform.datagridfield.row
import plone.schemaeditor.interfaces
import zope.interface

# example from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.z3cform.datagridfield
class ITableRowSchema(zope.interface.Interface): 
    one = schema.TextLine(title=u"One")
    two = schema.TextLine(title=u"Two")
    three = schema.TextLine(title=u"Three")

# new field factory for the zope.schema.interfaces.IObject
class DataGridFieldFactory(grok.GlobalUtility):
    grok.provides(plone.schemaeditor.interfaces.IFieldFactory)
    # this will show up in the schema editor vocabulary
    title = "DataGridField"

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # that's the horrid part as it will nail your field to this
        # specific schema
        kw = dict(value_type=collective.z3cform.datagridfield.row.DictRow(
            schema=ITableRowSchema))
        kwargs.update(kw)
        return zope.schema.List(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please have a look into: `plone.schemaeditor.fields.py` for more information about the field factory.

This will get you a basic datagrid for your content type. What's missing is the widget, which you currently can't be declared AFAIK.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, the TTW type editor can't handle it because it becomes cumbersome to define the DGF's schema as a sub-process to defining the content type's schema.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. From my understanding, what you're after is currently not supported. But, depending on your circumstances and given by the softwares possibilities (given by my example) you might get a semi-solution.